# Source attachment of JAR file not found

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc

I have downloaded the JAR-file sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0.jar and added it to my project in Eclipse (*Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add External JARs*). I can even see in the Package Explorer that the file has been added to the Referenced Libraries and when I click on the file, I see all the packages it contains and within them all the classes. However, when I try to open the documentation of a class, Eclipse tells me that the JAR-file has no source attachment. I have tried attaching the source, but then I get the message "*The source attachment does not contain the source for the file...*". Does anyone have an idea, why this may happen?

Answer (score 0):

Download and include source code jar [Documentation jar](https://sqlite.org/2017/sqlite-amalgamation-3210000.zip)

Comment: I still get the message "The source attachment does not contain the source for the file...". However, I see that the zip contains C++ files, while I am coding in Java...

Comment: check http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.21.0/sqlite-jdbc-3.21.0-sources.jar  or http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/3.21.0/

Comment: It works after I have included the first file. Thank you for your help!